# Hadoop can not start the thrift server, and Hue can't communicate with Hadoop namenode and datanode

Tags: hadoop, thrift, hue

I installed the hadoop CDH3u6 on 3 machines, but when I start the hadoop, I checked the namenode log, and find:

**2014-06-22 13:58:39,535 WARN org.apache.hadoop.util.PluginDispatcher: Unable to load dfs.namenode.plugins plugins**

So the hadoop thrift server can not start! and the Hue give an exception:

**Exception communicating with HDFS Namenode HUE Plugin at x.x.x.x:50903: Could not connect to x.x.x.x:50903**

My hadoop configs are as follows:
1. hdfs-site.xml

```
<property>
  <name>dfs.namenode.plugins</name>
  <value>org.apache.hadoop.thriftfs.NamenodePlugin</value>
  <description>Comma-separated list of namenode plugins to be activated.
  </description>
</property>
<property>
  <name>dfs.datanode.plugins</name>
  <value>org.apache.hadoop.thriftfs.DatanodePlugin</value>
  <description>Comma-separated list of datanode plugins to be activated.
  </description>
</property>
<property>
  <name>dfs.thrift.address</name>
  <value>0.0.0.0:50903</value>
</property>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the plugin jar installed? e.g. `/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/hue-plugins-2.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`

Could you list the hadoop packages?

Comment: Hi,Romain,thank you very much, I lost this hue plugin,it is fixed now.